# Prove that a finite Boolean ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times\cdots\times \mathbb Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $R$ is a finite Boolean ring with $1\neq 0$ then prove that $R\cong \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times \cdots\times \mathbb Z_2$.

How should I proceed? Please give some hints only.

Comment: Can you show that it is abelian? You might be able to use the structure theorem for finite abelian groups.

Comment: CameronWilliams: Beat me by a minute. And notice that every torsion is 2-torsion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hints:**
1.  $R$ is abelian.
2.  $R$ is a unitary $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-module.
3.  $R$ is a unitary free $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-module.

> Let $R$ be a boolean ring.  Clearly, $R$ is abelian and has characteristic $2$.  Therefore, $R$ is a unitary $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-module, or equivalently, a $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-vector space, because $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is a field.  Since every vector space over a field $F$ is a unitary free $F$-module, $R$ is a unitary free $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-module.  Hence, $R$ is a direct sum of some copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  If $R$ is, in addition, finite, then $R\cong\left(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\oplus n}=\left(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\right)^n$ as a $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-vector space for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  We shall induct on $n$ that $R\cong \left(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\oplus n}$ as a ring.  If $n=0$ or $n=1$, then the claim is trivial.  If $n>1$, then there exists an element $e\in R\setminus\{0,1\}$.  Clearly, $R=Re\oplus R(1-e)$, where $Re$ and $R(1-e)$ are boolean subrings of $R$, which are also ideals of $R$, with strictly smaller dimensions (over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$).  The induction hypothesis is applied to $Re$ and $R(1-e)$, so $Re\cong\left(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\dim_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}\big(Re\big)}$ and $R(1-e)\cong\left(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\dim_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}\big(R(1-e)\big)}$ as rings.  Consequently, we get $R\cong \left(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\dim_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}\big(Re\big)+\dim_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}\big(R(1-e)\big)}=\left(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\dim_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}(R)}=\left(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\right)^n$ as a ring.

Comment: I was giving hints.  I was only going to put my solution into the hidden portion.  But, you can leave your downvote there for all I care.

Comment: Does this actually account for the ring structure of $R$? It shows that its _additive_ structure must be as claimed, but as long as you're only looking at it as a module, what do you learn about the multiplication in $R$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm  You are very right.  Carelessly, I didn't think of that.  Fixed it now.  Then, my hints are indeed bad.  To the person who gave me an upvote, please take it back.  While I fixed my solution to use the hints, they can be avoided completely.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: {0, 1} comprises a subring (with unit) of $R$ with two elements. A ring with unit with just 2 elements is a field. Observe that $R$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over this field.